# Jersey GET endpoint not allowing multiple GET params

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I'm having issues making a Jersey endpoint accept more than one GET param. Here is the code for the method:

```
@GET
@Path("/get/spots_data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getSpotsData(@Context HttpServletResponse response, @QueryParam("function") String function_name, @QueryParam("limit") Integer spot_limit) {

    return "Happy Gilmore strikes again";
}
```

When calling the endpoint with curl, something like this:

```
curl -v http://localhost:9015/get/spots_data?function='whatever'&limit=40
```

And start debugging the method, the spot_limit is null...any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are those single quotes in your URL? Try replacing them with %27 and see what happens.

Comment: The first param is perfect, the problem is with the second one...but I'll give it a try

Comment: Single quotes are supposed to be URL-encoded, so I just guessed that that might be a problem. You could also just drop the quotes and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried both, nothing works, second paramaters keeps on being null...

Comment: Are you on linux? Sorry I didn't spot that earlier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being foiled by your shell. Quote your ampersand:

```
curl -v http://localhost:9015/get/spots_data?function='whatever'\&limit=40
```

Comment: Not really. & has meaning to your shell (it's used for backgrounding a job, and for describing standard inputs and outputs, depending on shell and context). Unless you escape it, your shell will interpret it and not pass it to curl.

Comment: Actually, you're right, the "&" was understood as send to background execution...lol